# Wordpress Query POST TITLE and POST TAGS

Tags: sql, wordpress, tags

Hello everyone in wordpress I was wondering how to QUERY the POST TITLE and the TAGS inside those POST. I have now queried the POST title POST date but Im missing the POST TAGS because it is located on different table and I dont know how to Select the TAGS inside each POST using query. Thank you, any reply is deeply appreciated thank you very much this is my code `SELECT ID,post_title,guid,post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status ='publish'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to run sql queries, you can use wordpress functions.
For tags you can use get_the_tags

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

For title you can use

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Make sure to use these codes inside the 'loop'

Comment: Hello Sir Priyam, I actually need these. I'm writing a custom plugin, I've made these codes before and show it in templates, but I want to display these in admin's dashboard. I have created custom page for my plugin, and I think these only works inside the loop on templates file like single.php, And the possiblity to display each Post title and its TAGS like shown in admin's dahsboard View All post. My plugin actually looks like it but the only thing missing is the TAGS

Comment: @DekDek Alright then you have to do the sql query. So basically you want a query to get tages of a particular post?

Comment: yes sir I think these should be how it works, but I don know what to compare because TAGS has wp_terms table but it has wp_terms_relationship etc. so it confuses me, I think these would be the code but It is not close enough `SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_terms.name, wp_posts.guid FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_terms  ON wp_posts.ID=wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='post' AND wp_posts.post_status ='publish'
`

Comment: There's no link between wp_posts.ID and wp_terms.term_id so the `wp_posts.ID=wp_terms.term_id ` join will not return anything meaningful

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_ID
LEFT JOIN wp_terms
ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_terms.name = 'x'
```